# get the selected file from the context menu and send it to the c# project

Tags: c#, windows, command-line-arguments

I am writing a program that adds scripts to the context menu, it works like this.

- (ContexMenu.exe) - adds a command to run the program with arguments
- type - file type called by the context menu
- * - all FILE - directory.
- name - file name displayed in the context menu.
- launch - command to launch.
- icon - icon in the context menu.

The launch command is entered into the launch

- (NLuaS.exe) - launches the lua script with arguments.
- script - lua script directory.
- path - the file from which the program was launched from the context menu (here is the question with this moment).

ContexMenu.exe

```cs
public void ContexAdd(string type, string name, string launch, string icon)
{
    // Создаем ключ реестра
    RegistryKey? regmenu = null;
    RegistryKey? regcmd = null;
    try
    {
        // Создаем ключ реестра с именем name и значением name в нем
        regmenu = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"" + type + "\\shell\\"+ name);
        regmenu.SetValue("", name);
        // Задаем иконку для контекстного меню
        regmenu.SetValue("Icon", icon);
        // Создаем ключ реестра для команды запуска
        regcmd = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@""+ type + "\\shell\\" + name + "\\command");
        // Задаем команду для запуска
        regcmd.SetValue("", launch);
        Console.WriteLine("Команда добавлена");
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(e); 
    }
    finally
    {
        // Закрываем ключи реестра
        if (regmenu != null) regmenu.Close();
        if (regcmd != null) regcmd.Close();
    }
}
```

NLuaS.exe

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(args[1]);
    Lua lua = new Lua();
    lua.LoadCLRPackage();
    lua["PATH"] = args[1];
    lua.DoFile(args[0]);
}
```

To add to the context menu I use the following command into my command line interface.

```
.\ContexMenu.exe 1 * GazLua "D:\MyRepository\LuaInterface\test\NLuaS.exe D:\MyRepository\LuaInterface\test\Lua\Doc.lua \'%1\'" null
```

But it doesn’t work like that, tell me how to transfer the file to run from the context menu, for example, to add the hello world file to the txt file.
It is also interesting how to specify which files to react to the context menu.

Comment: Remove the ``\`` before `'`, but  note that using `'...'` quoting will malfunction with file paths that happen to contain `'`. Better to use`"..."` quoting. From PowerShell, up to v7.2.x: `.\ContexMenu.exe 1 * GazLua 'D:\MyRepository\LuaInterface\test\NLuaS.exe D:\MyRepository\LuaInterface\test\Lua\Doc.lua \"%1\"'`. In v7.3+, omit the ``\``.